# How to change the JBoss 7 log configuration through Java?

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have added the custom logger in JBoss-7 standalone.xml and i have mentioned log file name such as /home/sample/sample.log and the log info is printing correctly in that location but **My requirement is "Need to change log name dynamically"**. I can change the log name through JBoss log cli command. ***"Is this possible to change the log file name via Java Code?"***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ModelControllerClient` and change everything you can from the CLI.

Eg:

```java
ModelNode op = new ModelNode();
op.get(ClientConstants.OP).set("change-file");
//change MYHANDLER 
op.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).set("/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=MYHANDLER");

//set new file name as new_file_name.log
ModelNode file = new ModelNode();
file.get("relative-to").set("jboss.server.log.dir");
file.get("path").set("new_file_name.log");
op.get("file").set(file);

ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9999);
ModelNode result = client.execute(op);

if (result.hasDefined("outcome") && "success".equals(result.get("outcome").asString())) {
    if (result.hasDefined("result")) {
        System.out.println(result.get("result"));
    }
} else if (result.hasDefined("failure-description")) {
    throw new RuntimeException(result.get("failure-description").toString());
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not successful; outcome = " + result.get("outcome"));
}
```

See also:

- [The native management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+native+management+API)
- [Monitor your JBoss resources using the DMR API](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/monitor-your-jboss-resources-using-the-dmr-api)

Comment: Thank you so much Federico for your quick response :).

Comment: @AzhaguvelA take a look in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164787/configuring-jboss-7-without-manually-editing-the-standalone-xml

Comment: How to stop ModelControllerClient opeartion after execute the command. which is keep running even if i use modelControllerClient.close();

Comment: No, The command is executing correctly and getting correct output as well but process is not terminated after completing.

Comment: Without seeing the code is not easy to determine if the behavior is correct or not. I think the best is make a new question with this problem.

Comment: May i know, How to update multiple properties at once. I have tried  to update using update-properties but it was not working correctly...